# php return global variable

Tags: php, global-variables

I have variable which may be set and contain some string, if not I need to find this string another way. I decided to use ternary operator with anonymous functions, first function is used when value of variable is set, second when not.

The problem is, the first function doesn't return any value, why not?

```
// This line is just for testing purposes so the first anonymous function is run
$variable = "value test";

$variable = isset($variable) ?
function() { global $variable; return $variable; } :
function() {
  $tmp = JFactory::GetDocument()->base;
  $tmp = explode('/', JFactory::GetDocument()->base);
  $tmp = explode('-', $tmp[count($tmp)-1]);
  unset($tmp[0]);

  return implode(' ', $tmp);  
};

print_r($variable);
```

Comment: Well, is it declared in the global scope, or is your shown excerpt within another method or function? (That's a *local* scope then.)

Comment: Would it be because in that first anonymous function, `$variable` is actually out of scope? You'll need to pass it in as a parameter, I think. But that does look like an incredibly convoluted piece of code - surely there's an easier way?

Comment: You aren't actually *executing* those functions. $variable will be a function, not a variable.

Comment: Im not sure whether my variable is really global or not, because my code is inside another code and I dont see whether its just included, or called like function, or etc... so that could be the point it doesnt work, but is there a way to access one level globalER variable?
...
I tried `print_r($variable())` as well, just forgot to write parentheses to my post too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was I was overwriting variable. I tried to return value of `variable` but assigned function to the very same `variable`, so the actual value was lost. So one way to fix this is rename variable, or to pass value to anonymous function.

```
//
// Rename variable
//
$variable1 = "value test";

$variable = isset($variable) ?
function() { GLOBAL $variable1; return $variable1; } :
function() { return false; };

var_dump($variable());


//
// Pass variable to anonymous function
//
$variable = "value test";

$variable = isset($variable) ?
function() use($variable) { return $variable; } :
function() {
    // ...
    return false;
};

var_dump($variable());
```

Answer (score 2):

The function probably does not return anything because `$variable` is not global, it lives in the caller's scope. You need to pass it as a parameter, or declare it global in the caller too.

But why use *two* anonymous functions? Couldn't you use:

```
$variable = isset($variable) ? $variable : function(){...}
```

Comment: Syntax for closure is adding ` use($value)` to the function prototype: `function() use ($value) {`

Answer (score 1):

Send the `$variable` into the anonymous function:

```
function($variable) {}
```

Comment: but then when I would like to get value of variable I would have to pass it to itself, `print_r($variable($variable))` ... of course I could create different variable for `isset` condition and different for storing return value of anonymous functions, but that's not that elegant